# Как сформировать переход по ссылке, используя текст из буфера обмена?

Tags: javascript, ссылки, clipboard

Приветствую.
Есть проект-трекер отслеживания выполнения задач. 
На каждой задаче есть определенный конкретный номер вида task01 (вместо 01 любой другой номер)
Есть кнопка, которая помещает данный номер в буфер обмена.
Вопрос: как силами JavaScript можно организовать следующее:
осуществляется переход по ссылке вида http://myserver.ru/tasks/task01 в новой вкладке по нажатию кнопки на экране? 
То есть JS должен читать содержимое буфера, и дописывать его в конец "постоянной части ссылки" вида "http://myserver.ru/tasks/".
Да и вообще, реально ли так сделать?
Спасибо.

Comment: Напрямую для любого браузера так точно не получится сделать, уверены что для этого вам нужен именно буфер обмена?

Comment: Не совсем, потому и спрашиваю..
Вообще у меня есть подобный функционал, реализованный на PHP - жму кнопку, номер задачи (вида task№№) копируется в буфер, потом вставляю данный номер в текстовое поле, жму другую кнопку - перехожу по ссылке.
но сейчас хочу реализовать данную фичу через расширение для браузера (копирую ссылку, жму на значок расширения и сразу меня перенаправляет по ссылке), а он с php же не дружит.
поправьте, если я не прав.

Comment: Откуда вообще изначально берется "`task01`"? Можно хоть в невидимый `div` это значение забросить или в качестве аттрибута какому-нибудь элементу. Или просто хранить в каком-нибудь js-объекте.

Comment: копирование ссылки происходит выделением текста с последующим `copy`? тогда можно навернуть костыль с перехватыванием этого значения на стороне js

Comment: номер таска присваивается по порядку (не мной). то есть кто-то создал новую задачу, у нее номер, например, 90. Следующий номер другой задачи будет 91 и так далее. На это я влиять не могу, есть только возможность скопировать данный номер в буфер и все.

Comment: так номер таски вы потом в браузере копируете в буфер руками выделением + `copy`? уверены что это значение нигде на странице не хранится?

Comment: уверен, да.....